# How does one set a logarithmic scale in a ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

How does one set a logarithmic scale for both `x` and `y` axes in `ContourPlot` in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One possibility is to plot the contour plot with linear scales using `ContourPlot` and use `ListLogLogPlot` to transform this plot to one with logarithmic scales:

```
pl = Normal@
  ContourPlot[
   Sin[3 x] + Cos[3 y] == 1/2, {x, .01 Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, .01 Pi, 3 Pi}, 
   PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLogLogPlot[Cases[pl, Line[a_, b___] :> a, Infinity], 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I keep missing the fun questions.  Nice answer. +1

Comment: Great idea! I never thought of that.

Comment: One disadvantage this method might have is that of point sampling. The right hand and the upper parts are better sampled than the left hand and lower parts of the plot. This might lead to curves that are less smooth on one side than on the other.

Comment: I think that there are actually a lot of other limitations... It's a pity the scaling functions are still not available to this type of plot... For instance, as long as we choose a simple option like ContourLabels, everything becomes more messy...

Comment: Hahllelujah! Now if only they would provide better Tick control options for Log Plots

Answer (score 28):

Instead of doing some transformation on the original `ContourPlot` we can do an exponential rescaling of the original variables in the `ContourPlot`, so this is somewhat different approach to get roughly the same result :

```
ContourPlot[ Sin[ 3 Exp@x] + Cos[ 3 Exp@y ] == 1/2, 
             {x, Log[0.01 Pi], Log[3 Pi]}, {y, Log[0.01 Pi], Log[3 Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

The only difference is a different coordinate system.

Comment: The downside is the ticks placement and labels.

Comment: @becko If you had read the answer below you wouldn't have mentioned this at all.

Answer (score 18):

As of M11, you can use the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) option:

```
ContourPlot[
    Sin[3 x]+Cos[3 y]==1/2,
    {x,.01 Pi,3 Pi},
    {y,.01 Pi,3 Pi},
    ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that I'm six months late to this answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this option is just a patch job, it just log's the data and relabels the axes in one step, therefore you cannot combine this plot with other true log plots e.g. LogListPlot.

Comment: @Jay Can you provide an example where plots can't be combined? Perhaps in another question.

Comment: There is a simple workaround: use scaling functions for ListPlot instead of LogListPlot.. I don't know if this warrants it's own question.

Comment: What if I wanted to Log only one axis? what would I replace "Log" with for the one I wanted to stay linear?

Answer (score 15):

As a slight variation of the nice suggestion above add `FrameTicks` to get the tick labels you want.

```
ContourPlot[
 Sin[3 Exp[x]] + Cos[3 Exp[y]] == 1/2, {x, Log[0.01 Pi], 
  Log[3 Pi]}, {y, Log[0.01 Pi], Log[3 Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
 FrameTicks -> {Table[{y, ToString[Round[10^y, 0.001]]}, {y, 
     Log[10, 0.001], Log[10, 100]}], 
   Table[{y, ToString[Round[10^y, 0.001]]}, {y, Log[10, 0.001], 
     Log[10, 100]}]}]
```

Comment: Your example uses a base-E log scale for the plotting and a base-10 log scale for the ticks. Shouldn't these be consistent?