# Epilog->Text placement on LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting

Hopefully this is a simple question. I'm trying to overlay some text on top of a `LogLogPlot` using `Epilog` and `Text`. However, I'm struggling with the coordinates that `Text` seems to be using for placement. For example:

```
LogLogPlot[x + Sin[2x], {x, 1, 1000},
  Epilog -> Style[Text["x+sin(2x)", {5, 5}], 14]]
```

places the label "x+sin(x)" at roughly {x,y}={150,150} on the plot's coordinate system, and not {5,5} as in the input. However, if I change the LogLogPlot to just Plot, the label will get placed at {5,5} (or wherever I specify). What's going on?

How it looks right now:

[image: graph]

Comment: You have to use `Log` on the coordinates, this works: `LogLogPlot[x + Sin[2 x], {x, 1, 1000}, 
 Epilog -> Style[Text["x+sin(2x)", {Log[5], Log[5]}], 14]]`

Comment: @Anon  You just beat me.  If you want, I'll delete my answer and let you answer. ?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I only beat you to it because I was too lazy to create that image. Your answer deserved to get accepted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently the `Epilog` is processed after the coordinate remapping.  `Log[{150., 150.}]` ~ `{5., 5.}`.  Try this if you want the label at `{5, 5}`:

```
LogLogPlot[x + Sin[2 x], {x, 1, 1000}, 
 Epilog -> Style[Text["x+sin(2x)", Log@{5, 5}], 14]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I love those four-character fixes!

Comment: That works perfectly... interesting, though, that while the log scales are in base 10, you must supply the log base e of the coordinates.

Comment: @user1748343 If you want to see what's being used, select the graphics, and execute the menu item Cell > Show Expression. It'll be long.  But *search* for CoordinatesToolOptions.  You'll see the functions used.

Comment: There's no need to *search* for it; just use `Options[(*graphic*), CoordinatesToolOptions]`

Comment: slightly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27109/how-to-draw-a-circle-in-a-graph-with-log-y-scale