# How to do the log scale plot for ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

My current code is:

```
data = {{0.1, 0.1, 2}, {0.1, 0.2, 1}, {0.2, 0.1, 1}, {0.2, 0.2, 2}};
ListContourPlot[data, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}]]
```

It produces the following figure:

[image]

I want to scale the linear x and y axes to a log scale without converting to log units.

There is a ListLogLogPlot function but no corresponding ListLogLogContourPlot function.

I have read several relevant threads:

- How does one set a logarithmic scale in a ContourPlot?:
  [How does one set a logarithmic scale in a ContourPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-does-one-set-a-logarithmic-scale-in-a-contourplot)
- Scale ContourPlot axes:
  http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Jun/msg00585.html

However, they are all for ContourPlot rather than ListContourPlot.

I tried to use way suggested by [How does one set a logarithmic scale in a ContourPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-does-one-set-a-logarithmic-scale-in-a-contourplot):

```
data = {{0.1, 0.1, 2}, {0.1, 0.2, 1}, {0.2, 0.1, 1}, {0.2, 0.2, 2}};
pl = Normal@
  ListContourPlot[data, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}]]
ListLogLogPlot[Cases[pl, Line[a_, b___] :> a, Infinity], 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][2]]
```

However, it only produces the following, in which the density color background is lost, leaving only lines:

[image]

The way suggested by http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Jun/msg00585.html by using FrameTicks functions seems promising. But, it is for ContourPlot. I do not know how to adopt it to be used in ListContourPlot.

Helps are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract FrameTicks using AbsoluteOptions and convert it to log scale.
I used different data set to see log scale more easily:

```
data = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[3 x] + Cos[3 y]}, {x, .1 Pi, 2 Pi, .2}, {y, .01 Pi, 2 Pi, .2}], 1];

pdata = ListContourPlot[data, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3];

ticks = FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[pdata, FrameTicks];

logticks = Apply[If[#1 == 0, {#1, , ##3}, {Log[10, #1], ##2}] &, ticks, {2}];

ListContourPlot[{Log[10, #1], Log[10, #2], #3} & @@@ data, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}], 
  FrameTicks -> logticks]
```

[image]

Comment: This one is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Under Mathematica 10, I am getting error "Ticks::ticks: "{Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification." and no ticks are shown. Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Mathematica 10.2 : "Ticks::ticks: "{Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification."

Answer (score 3):

In M11.2, you can just use the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) option:

```
data = Flatten[
    Table[{x,y,Sin[3 x]+Cos[3 y]},{x,.1 Pi,2 Pi,.2},{y,.01 Pi,2 Pi,.2}],
    1
];

ListContourPlot[
    data,
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Log","Log"},
    Mesh->None, PlotRange->All, InterpolationOrder->3
]
```

[image]

Comment: I just love it! I wish all plotting & graphics functions had `ScalingFunction` options and the mess with `LogLog`, `Log` and `LogLinear` would end forever!

Answer (score 1):

It's very ugly way but sometimes it is good to have it rather than nothing.

It's about manually taking `Polygon`s and plotting them with `Log10` applied to vertices. To not bother with creating custom ticks I've just used `Overlay` with `ImagePadding` to set everything straight:

```
Overlay[{
         Graphics[(pl[[1, 1]] /. x : {_?NumberQ ..} :> Log10[x]), ImagePadding -> 25],
         ListLogLogPlot[Cases[pl, Line[a_, b___] :> a, Infinity], Joined -> True, 
                        Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> 25, 
                        AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][2]]
        }]
```

[image]