# How to change the scale of a ListContourPlot to logarithmic and combine it with a LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

My questions are:

1) how can I change the compressed scale to fine one like `{y = 0.1, 1, 10}, {x = 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100}`.

```
data = Flatten[
         Table[
           {x, y, Sin[3 x] + Cos[3 y]}, 
           {x, .1 Pi, 2 Pi, .2}, {y, .01 Pi, 2 Pi, .2}
         ],
         1
       ];

pdata = ListContourPlot[data, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3];

ticks = FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[pdata, FrameTicks];

logticks = Apply[If[#1 == 0, {#1, , ##3}, {Log[10, #1], ##2}] &, ticks, {2}];

ListContourPlot[{Log[10, #1], Log[10, #2], #3} & @@@ data, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}], 
  FrameTicks -> logticks]
```

2) how can I combine two plots in one figure. The two plots are a `ListContourPlot` and `LogLinearPlot`.

This is my figure with Michael E2 code.

I want to plot a curve

```
LogLinearPlot[1 + 0.5/xx^0.33, {xx, 0.01, 105}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

on the figure without any change in figure

Comment: *Whenever possible,* questions should be written with a minimal code example in the post, and avoid links to external files - not just for security reasons but also because those links almost invariably go bad after a while, making the question unclear to future readers.

Comment: Any help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Shabaan, I see that your code comes from this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35038/27951. Unfortunately, however, as mentioned in the comments to that answer as well, `AbsoluteOptions` has been essentially abandoned by WRI and doesn't work properly anymore. You may notice that it fails to extract the ticks, so your `ticks` variable is a list of empty lists; consequently `logticks` doesn't make sense either. That solution simply won't work. You could look at the alternative solution proposed in the same post instead.

Comment: I need List contour plot with good logarithmic scale!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first question, you can do this:

```
ListContourPlot[MapAt[Log, data, {All, ;; 2}], 
 Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, 
      Exp}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notes: (1) I changed `Log10` to `Log` -- it must match the functions in `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks ``, something I overlooked initially. (2) Also, if you have V9+, `MapAt[Log, data, {All, ;; 2}]`, which was pointed out by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard), is more efficient than `{Log@#1, Log@#2, #3} & @@@ data` and perhaps a little clearer; otherwise, stick to the `@@@` form.

For the second question, plots can be combined with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).  Perhaps something like this is what is sought:

```
Show[
 ListContourPlot[
  MapAt[Log, data, {All, 1}] (* {Log@#1, #2, #3}& @@@ data *),
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}], 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
     Automatic}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}],
 LogLinearPlot[3 + 2 Sin[x], {x, .1 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Consider using `MapAt[Log10, data, {All, ;; 2}]` in place of `{Log[10, #1], Log[10, #2], #3} & @@@ data`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep, if I had considered refactoring the OP's code at all, that's probably what I would have done.  Thanks.

Comment: This code give the following message     MapAt::psl: Position specification {All,1;;2} in MapAt[Log10,{{0.314159,0.0314159,1.80458},{0.314159,0.231416,1.57755},<<47>>,{0.514159,3.43142,0.354367},<<910>>},{All,1;;2}] is not an integer or a list of integers. >>

Comment: For the second question: I have LogLinearPlot give to me curve I want to plot it above the contour figure

Comment: @Shaaban Ah, you must have V8 or earlier, perhaps?  That form of `Map` was introduced in V9, I believe. -- Re 2nd Q: Is the contour figure a regular linear-linear plot that needs converting to log-linear? It should be able to be converted to log-linear with `{Log@#1], #2, #3} & @@@ data` and using `{Automatic, Automatic}` for the second pair of the `FrameTicks` option.

Comment: first of all thank you. I need a way to combine the ListContourPlot and LogLinearPlot in one figure without change in the Log scale like figure in the top of the page

Comment: @Shaaban Ah, you want to convert the log-linear plot into a log-log plot, then?  I guessed the other way.  Why not just use `LogLogPlot` instead of `LogLinearPlot` and combine the contour plot and it with `Show`?

Comment: Thanks It's finally works your are the best.

Comment: @Shaaban You're welcome.  And thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Although tick locations and values cannot be extracted from `pdata` using `AbsoluteOptions`, they can nonetheless be extracted.

```
tckx = Table[{Log[10, i], i}, {i, 
   Ceiling@Min@Cases[pdata[[1, 1]], {z_, _} -> z, Infinity], 
   Floor@Max@Cases[pdata[[1, 1]], {z_, _} -> z, Infinity]}];    
tcky = Table[{Log[10, i], i}, {i, 
   Ceiling@Min@Cases[pdata[[1, 1]], {_, z_} -> z, Infinity], 
   Floor@Max@Cases[pdata[[1, 1]], {_, z_} -> z, Infinity]}];
```

and then included in the plot, as desired.

```
ListContourPlot[{Log[10, #1], Log[10, #2], #3} & @@@ data, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{tcky, None}, {tckx, None}}]
```

[image]

FYI, `pdata[[1, 1]]` is the internal list of points from which `pdata` is constructed.  In this particular case, `tckx` and `tcky` are the same:

```
tckx // N
(* {{0., 1.}, {0.30103, 2.}, {0.477121, 3.}, 
    {0.60206, 4.}, {0.69897, 5.}, {0.778151, 6.}} *)
```

**Alternative Approach**

Alternatively, do not use `pdata` at all.  Instead, define

```
tck[min_, max_] := Table[{Log[10, i], i}, {i, Ceiling[10^min], Floor[10^max]}]
```

in which case

```
ListContourPlot[{Log[10, #1], Log[10, #2], #3} & @@@ data, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"LakeColors", "Reverse"}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{tck, None}, {tck, None}}]
```

produces the same plot as before.

Comment: Consider using `MapAt[Log10, data, {All, ;; 2}]` in place of `{Log[10, #1], Log[10, #2], #3} & @@@ data`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Certainly, your option works well.  What are the tradeoffs from your perspective.

Comment: Mostly just brevity. :-)