# Logarithmic scale in a contour plot

Tags: plotting

How to graph the function $$ \frac{E(\sigma_\rho,\sigma_z)}{N\hbar\bar{\omega}}=\frac{\bar{a}^2}{4}\left(\frac{2}{\sigma_\rho^2}+\frac{1}{\sigma_z^2}\right)+\frac{1}{4\bar{a}^2\lambda^{2/3}}(2\sigma_\rho^2+\lambda^2\sigma_z^2)+\frac{N}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\bar{a}^2}{\sigma_\rho^2\sigma_z}\left[ a-\epsilon_{dd}f_s(y)\right] $$ in logarithmic scale? Were $N=20 000$, $\bar{a}=1.37\times10^{-5}$, $a=9.54\times10^{-10}$,$\epsilon_{dd}=8.48\times10^{-10}$ e $f_s(y)=-2$.

My code:

```
ContourPlot[((1.37*10^{-5})^2)/
4 (2/x^2 + 
 1/y^2) + (2 x^2 + (10)^2 y^2)/(4 (1.37*10^{-5})^2 (10)^{2/
    3}) + (20000)/
Sqrt[2 Pi] ((1.47*10^{-5})/x)^2 (1/
 y) ((9.54*10^{-10}) - (8.48*10^{-10}) (-2)), {x, 0, 10^2}, {y, 0.1,10}]
```

Correct graph
[image]

My graph
[image]

Comment: Post code, not images of code.  Edit your  post and add the code. Use the `{}` to format the block.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87979/how-to-change-the-scale-of-a-listcontourplot-to-logarithmic-and-combine-it-with) has ways for `ListContourPlot`, which should be able to be adapted to this case.

Comment: possible duplicate Q/A:
 [How does one set a logarithmic scale in a ContourPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5265/125)

Comment: Is that the energy landscape for a self-trapped dipolar droplet in an ultracold Bose gas?

Comment: @march. Yes. I'm new in Mathematica. Do you any good manual?