# ListContourPlot in Log scale

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I am making a ListContourPlot but want the y-axis in the log scale. I almost got everything from the thread [How to do the log scale plot for ListContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35032/how-to-do-the-log-scale-plot-for-listcontourplot). But there both the axes are put to Log scale. In particular, I am unable to understand the function of the lines:

```
ticks = FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[pdata, FrameTicks];
logticks = Apply[If[#1 == 0, {#1, , ##3}, {Log[10, #1], ##2}] &, ticks, {2}];
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Does your version of *Mathematica* have `ScalingFunctions`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes it does.