# Log transformation (in dimensions) of an image

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform

Is there an easy way to do a log-transformation of an image? I'm not taking about the colours, but the geometry. The difficulty is to extrapolate pixels and round-offs.

For example, an white image with horizontal dots whose $x$-coordinates follow a power law would be transformed to a white image with regularly spaced dots.

Comment: There was a related question: [How does one set a logarithmic scale in a ContourPlot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-does-one-set-a-logarithmic-scale-in-a-contourplot). I guess this is a duplicate, otherwise you should explain more clearly your expectations.  Moreover you should take a closer look at the [logarithmic-scale](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logarithmic-scale) tag.

Comment: The difference is that an imported image is not the same type as a plot: that are pixels instead of numbers. I tried the code to make sure and I get an error `ListLogLogPlot called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`

Comment: I'm afraid that it is very unclear to me what you want to accomplish, especially when you mention "the geometry". Could you be more specific, and possibly provide an example?

Comment: @MarcoB I insist on _geometry_, in contrast to colour, because it is more natural to think of log as an application over the pixels (resulting in a change of contrast). Here, I would like to distort the image in such a way that points near the left end would be moved to the left, and the more a point is initially on the right, the more it is move to the left (log transformation). I understand it might not be very clear. Unfortunately, I don't see how I can give an example as it is exactly what I am trying to do. I'll think about it and try to find a reformulation with illustration if possible.

Comment: Maybe you could try to describe your envisioned process when applied to a small array of values (say, 10x10) standing in for your image.

Comment: [`ImageTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTransformation.html) and [`ImageForwardTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageForwardTransformation.html) are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Bill I tried your suggestion. There's a little bug because `Floor[E^x]+1` can get larger than the size of `pixels`. I think you were in the right spirit, but anyway the functions indicated by shrx's do exactly what I want!

Comment: @shrx Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. If you can answer with `linearimage = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];     
ImageForwardTransformation[linearimage, {(#[[1]] + 1) // 
    Log, #[[2]]} &]` I'll will accept your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve the desired transformation with the [`ImageForwardTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageForwardTransformation.html) function.
The transformation effect is easily visible on a grid image:

```
grid = Rasterize[
  Graphics[Rectangle[], 
   GridLines -> {Range[.05, .95, .05], Range[.05, .95, .05]}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[{White, Thick}], 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> 300]]
```

[image: linear grid]

You can do the transformation on both dimensions

```
ImageResize[
 ImageForwardTransformation[grid, Log[# + 0.1] &, PlotRange -> All], 
 ImageDimensions[grid]]
```

[image: log grid both axes]

or just on one (x in this example):

```
ImageResize[
 ImageForwardTransformation[grid, {Log[#[[1]] + 0.1], #[[2]]} &, 
  PlotRange -> All], ImageDimensions[grid]]
```

[image: log grid x coordinate]

Unfortunately, you can't explicitly set the `Method` used in the interpolation of the transformed image by choosing an option from the [`Resampling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resampling.html) documentation. You can only switch between the `Automatic` method or `None`.

Comment: When you know the inverse function, it's better to use `ImageTransformation` since then you benefit from good interpolation, etc. Like that: `ImageTransformation[grid, InverseFunction[Log[# + 0.1] &], 
 ImageDimensions[grid], PlotRange -> All]`