# How do I change the scale on a plot so different parts of the axis are on different scales?

Tags: plotting

I have to make a simple plot using the `Plot` function. However on the $x$ axis I want the scale to be such that it initially shows a zoom up of $0$ to $1$, and then the scale compresses and shows from, say, $100$ to $10000$. 
How to achieve that? I have tried a lot of different functions including `Zoom` and `Show`, but none seem to work.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate,  see e.g. [How does one set a logarithmic scale in a ContourPlot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-does-one-set-a-logarithmic-scale-in-a-contourplot)

Comment: Thanks. That might work. However is there no other alternative method?

Comment: You could take a look at [Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/27951) and solutions therein. Perhaps something could be adapted.

Comment: What happens between 1 and 100?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

You can split your X interval into several subintervals and sample your function inside every interval with step proportional to current interval length. Then use `ListPlot` to show all sampled values and relabel X-axis ticks.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] + 1.5;
nPoints = 1000.0;
edges = {0, 2 Pi, 10 Pi, 100 Pi};
intervals = Partition[#, 2, 1] &@edges;
points = Flatten[
   Range[#[[1]], #[[2]], (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/nPoints][[1 ;; -2]] & /@ 
    intervals];
ticks = Transpose@{Range[1, Length@edges*nPoints, nPoints], edges};

Show[ListPlot[f[points], Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about if you just use a simple Manipulate statement? For example:

```
Manipulate[Plot[x, {x, 0, a}], {a, {1, 100, 1000}}]
```

That should work. Even more, you can choose the plot options according to your choice of *a*, that you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks guys. LogLinearPlot worked fine for me.

Comment: @BudhadityaBhattacharjee .. interesting... how is a log scale a zoom in? But I'm glad you got what you wanted.