# Manipulate axis scale on a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, scaling

Use this code to generate my problem

```
n = Join[Table[i, {i, 6, 100, 10}], Table[i, {i, 100, 600, 50}]];

m = 247(*kg*);
L = 6.8(*m*);
II = 4.55*10^-5(*m^4*);
EE = 2.1*10^11(*Pa*);

m = N@Table[247/n[[i]], {i, 1, Length[n]}];

k = Table[
   1.61 ((E II)/(2 (L/n[[i]]))^3) (L/n[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[n]}];

M = Table[ m[[i]] IdentityMatrix[n[[i]] - 1], {i, 1, Length[n]}];

K = Table[
   Table[0, {j, 1, n[[k]] - 1}, {i, 1, n[[k]] - 1}], {k, 1, 
    Length[n]}];

For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[n], ii++, 
 For[j = 1, j <= n[[ii]] - 1, j++, 
  For[i = 1, i <= n[[ii]] - 1, 
   i++, {If[j == i, K[[ii, j, i]] = 2 k[[ii]], Nothing], 
    If[i == j + 1, K[[ii, j, i]] = -k[[ii]], Nothing], 
    If[i == j - 1, K[[ii, j, i]] = -k[[ii]], Nothing]}]]]

sol = Sqrt[
   Table[Eigenvalues[N[Inverse[M[[i]]]].K[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[n]}]];

freqtable = 
  Table[Table[(Reverse@sol[[i]])[[j]], {i, 1, Length[n]}], {j, 1, 5}];

freqPoints = Table[Transpose[{n[[All]], freqtable[[i]]}], {i, 1, 5}];

ListPlot[freqPoints, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(1\
\)], \(2\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(2\)], \(2\)]\)",
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(3\)], \
\(2\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(4\)], \(2\)]\)",
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(5\)], \
\(2\)]\)"}, AxesLabel -> {"N", "rad/s"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier New", FontSize -> 10}]
```

This should produce you the following plot
[image]

Now the problem is that I have to plot this from 0-600, but as you can see, nothing really interesting happens for N greater than 100.

So what I want is to somehow show more of the 0-100 part and show less of the 100-600 part. Is there a way to somehow rescale the x-axis?

Comment: Related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109748/how-do-i-change-the-scale-on-a-plot-so-different-parts-of-the-axis-are-on-differ/109760#109760)

Comment: Replace `ListPlot` with `ListLogLinearPlot`