# $\log_q \log_q$ plot instead of $\log \log$ plot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, logarithmic-scale

By defining the $\log_q$ as:
$$ \log_q(x)=\frac{x^{1-q}-1}{1-q}, x \geq 0, q \neq 1$$
how would it be possible to have the equivalent of the `LogLogPlot` command, meaning that the axes are now defined as $\log_q (x)$ and $\log _q f(x)$?

The reason I am asking this, is because I would like to make a plot of the *Tsallis q-Gaussian* distributions which are built-in *Mathematica* [Tsallis Q Gaussian](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TsallisQGaussianDistribution.html) and then the equivalent of the `LogLogPlot` in order to show that these distributions about power laws on a $q$-logarithmic scale.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `ParametricPlot[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Can you please explain in more detailed what do you mean by this suggestion? As far as I am concerned I just know that `LogLogPlot` defines logarithmic scales on both axes but I am not familiar with the way Mathematica does that, therefore my problem is my lack of ability to manipulate this command.

Comment: A hint: compare `LogLogPlot[Exp[x], {x, 1, 5}]` and `ParametricPlot[{Log[x], Log[Exp[x]]}, {x, 1, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`. (Worry about the ticks later; concentrate on what these transformations are doing mathematically.)

Comment: @J.M. I will try out Mr Wizard's answer in order to see if that works out for me. Thank you again :)

Comment: there is nothing special about `LogLog` plot. You can always make transformation and then produce special ticks/gridlines, something like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109748/how-do-i-change-the-scale-on-a-plot-so-different-parts-of-the-axis-are-on-differ/109760#109760)

Comment: Calling that function $\log_q$ is really misleading.  That notation is standard for the base-$q$ logarithm.

Comment: @Szabolcs It is the inverse of the Tsallis q exponential, but my post has more to do with the q-logaritmic scale axes rather than the function itself. This is why I defined it at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to make use of [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html).

```
lq[q_ /; q != 1][x_] := (x^(1 - q) - 1)/(1 - q)
invlq[q_][z_] := Abs[(1 + z - q z)^(1/(1 - q))]

spec[q_] := {{lq[q], invlq[q]}, {lq[q], invlq[q]}};

Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 30}, PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> spec[0.8]]
```

[image]

This works in *Mathematica* 10.1 but it is not officially supported, as indicated by the Option name being highlighted in red.

Comment: In this case, the OP seems to want to plot `tqpdf[x_, q_] = PDF[TsallisQGaussianDistribution[q], x]`; maybe you can use that example instead (making sure you are using the same `q` for it and `lq[]`). For reference: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsallis_statistics#Tsallis_functions) are complete definitions you can use for `spec[]`.

Comment: @J.M. I really don't know how that should look so I feel uncomfortable with it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you, I will take some time to play around with it, perhaps also use the `TsallisQGaussianDistribution` to see if I get what is expected by it and then I will get back to you.